# Replace content by class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I modify the content with Javascript selecting the elements by class?

Actually I tried using this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass").innerHTML = "new content"
```

But does nothing.
If I select the element by ID it's work

```
document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = "new content"
```

But I need can select by class.

I only need to change the content inside a  tag. Replacing a text to an img element for a woocommerce buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will return array. So loop that array and do your logic:

```js
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "new content";
  }
```

```html
<div class="myClass">old content</div>
<div class="myClass">old content</div>
```

Comment: That's not very functional of JavaScript to require that. Ideally it would apply the result of the function to each and every instance of the class by default. An overloaded method would be reasonable in this context.

Answer (score 3):

**getElementsByClassName** returns an array so you have to loop that array to change the content having your given class. You can try following to code. I hope it will help you.

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i].innerHTML = "new content";
}
```

Comment: yes, it is a coincidence, while I was answering justinas had already answered. The only difference is of variable name.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out getElementsByClass returns an array.
If you are willing to use jquery it could simplify as

```
$(".myClass").html("new content")
```

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) also provides the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator, which can be used to transform the HTMLCollection returned by getElementsBYClassName into a regular array and then combine it with forEach(), to change all array elements with the new content, with the line:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')].forEach(element => {
    element.innerHTML = '<div>New Content</div>' }
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array, as classes are not unique, whereas `document.getElementById` returns just an object (it should be unique).

Long story short, try `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[i].innerHTML = "new content"` where i can take values from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of elements with the `.myclass` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is not unique. i.e The same class name is used by many other elements. So `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")` this will retrun an array containing all the classes. So, either you need to select the porper class by `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0]` or assign some id to that particular element.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are returned in an array, so you need to iterate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), i;
for (i in elems) {
    elems[i].innerHTML = "new content";
}
```

Comment: Why do you loop all elements instead of taking only elements with class name?

Comment: Try adjust this answer to use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: ugly variable declaration put i in a new line pls.